# Update current item in List A using information from most current item in List B - SP 2010

Tags: workflow, designer-workflow, workflow-activity, workflow-variable

Help,

Is it possible to update the most current item in List A using information from the most current item in List B?

I have to use SharePoint 2010 so functionality is limited. I have no been able to figure this out thus far. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Can you explain if there are any patterns or possible associations between the items in list A and list B? Is there anything besides "Last Modified" that would make them be able to identify each other?, Perhaps, just give more exact detail on what you are trying to accomplish column wise, information wise. Thanks!